# What Node.js frameworks utilize the Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm contemplating giving node.js a try and have been trying to find an environment that is similar to Rails and Activerecord. After a lot of research and googling, I've come to the conclusion that the Sequelize ORM is a pretty good starting point.  What I can't quite figure out is what Node.js frameworks utilize Sequelize or does adopting Sequelize mean that I forego the framework all together.

I know that [Metamarkets has adopted Sequelize](http://metamarkets.com/2012/node-js-for-the-enterprise/).  I'd be interested in hearing from anyone who is using Sequelize and to learn what your development stack is. Any color you can offer on the environment and your experience would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only speak from personal experience, as I don't know who is using Sequelize. I've played with it for a while and I personally decided to not use it for two main reasons

1. No transaction support.  Unlike other SQL orms for node sequelize currently does not support transactions.  The developer said he is working on this but couldn't give a timeline for when it would be done and seemed to indicate it would be a while.
2. At least for MySQL, building foreign key relationships did not actually create foreign keys in the schema.  I really didn't like this since I wanted to be able to synch my schema with the data objects using sequelize, but whats the point of foreign keys if the database doesn't enforce it as such?

Those things go against my personal database preferences so I am not using it.  However, the developer is active and the code is well done, so if these things are addressed I'd happily go back to it.

EDIT:

It even looks like the people you linked to had some issues with it as well:

> we had to make a few contributions: introducing joins for collection getters, and adding connection pooling.

For me, as a non production user, I didn't want to have to build this into my ORM.

Comment: +1 for sharing my opinion about foreign key constraints not actually being enforce

Comment: I just want to add that those features are planned for 1.7.0: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize#170